# DNS setting changes after laptop being on work network

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10

At my office I have a Windows 2012 server in a small office away from home. After going to the office and coming home, my laptop WIFI network settings have changed so that the DNS server is no longer set to "Obtain automatically" but instead has the IP of the Windows Server. As I'm on my home network the local IP address of the Windows Server is not accessible so all name resolution fails and it appears that I have no working internet.

I have to manually change my network interface settings to DHCP when I get home, but going back to the office will change it back again automatically.

Everything should work if the setting is left to automatic, both at home and at the office. The office router knows to use the Windows Server for DNS queries so it is transparent to all the laptops.

I can't work out what is changing the setting and how to stop it.

This happens with everyone elses laptops as well (Windows 10 Pro) although I don't think I've had to explain the fix to the guy with Windows 7 Pro, so maybe it is something specific to windows 10?

Comment: Perhaps the router at home is not the same as the router at the office.  (Just a remote possibility, ;-)  remote, get it?)

Comment: When you login at the office, you are getting a networking policy applied to your computer.

Comment: This is likely a group policy issue.